# Is Satan a being or just a mission any angel could fulfill?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, malach-angel, job-iyov-book-of

Midrash B"R quoted by Rashi ([Genesis.32.30](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.32.30?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he), and similarly [Judges.13.18](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Judges.13.18?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he)) says that:

> "We [angels] have no fixed names; our names change, all depending upon the **service we are commanded to carry out** as the errand with which we are charged (Genesis Rabbah 78:4)."

In the Book of Job, does this principle apply to Satan also, i.e. it is just a mission any angel could be called on or is he a stand-alone entity/creation?

Comment: Is there a problem you have with the answer implied in the question, that his job was לשטן?

Comment: Can we even talk about angels independently of their jobs?